# How to fix angular in updating the data

Tags: php, angular

I can't update the data. What's wrong with my code? I took it many times and I tried to fix this, but nothing happens. I felt so complicated because I have no mentor about this. I am beginner to handle this kind of application so I need mentor right now to fix this problem

**HTML**:

```html
<tbody *ngIf="ediTradingPartners?.length">
  <tr *ngFor="let data of ediTradingPartners">

    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.tp_name }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" *ngIf="showMyContainer">{{ data.tp_name }}</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.interchange_id }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" value="PUT" *ngIf="showMyContainer">{{ data.interchange_id }}</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.creation_date }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" *ngIf="showMyContainer"> {{ data.creation_date }} </textarea>
    </td>
    <td>

      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.created_by }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" *ngIf="showMyContainer"> {{ data.created_by }} </textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.update_date }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" *ngIf="showMyContainer">{{ data.update_date }}</textarea>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.updated_by }}
      </div>
      <textarea class="cell-data" *ngIf="showMyContainer"> {{ data.updated_by }}</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div *ngIf="!showMyContainer">
        {{ data.tmx_interchange_id }}
      </div>
      <textarea *ngIf="showMyContainer" class="cell-data">{{ data.tmx_interchange_id }}</textarea>
    </td>

    <td class="btn-group" n>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="showMyContainer=!showMyContainer" *ngIf="showMyContainer" (click)="save(data)">        
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" (click)="showMyContainer=!showMyContainer" class="btn btn-warning">     
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>

    </td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**TypeScript**

```ts
export class ListOfPartnersComponent implements OnInit {
  editForm: FormGroup;
  ediTradingPartners: EdiTradingPartner[];

  id: string;
  tp_name: string;
  interchange_id: string;
  tmx_interchange_id: string;
  data: any;

  mode: boolean;
  showMyContainer: boolean = false;

  constructor(private ediTradingPartnerService: EdiTradingPartnerService,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private plat: PlatformLocation) {
    this.id = "";
    this.tp_name = "";
    this.interchange_id = "";
    this.tmx_interchange_id = "";
  }
  get f() {
    return this.editForm.controls;
  }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.ediTradingPartnerService.getEdiTradingPartners()
      .subscribe(EdiTradingPartner => this.ediTradingPartners = EdiTradingPartner);

    if (localStorage.getItem("userType") != "guest") {
      this.mode = true;
    }

  }
  getUser(EdiTradingPartnerId) {
    this.ediTradingPartnerService.getEdiTradingPartnerById(parseInt(EdiTradingPartnerId))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.ediTradingPartners = data;
        console.log(this.ediTradingPartners)
        this.f.id.setValue(this.ediTradingPartners[0].id);
        this.f.interchange_id.setValue(this.ediTradingPartners[0].tp_name);
        this.f.tp_name.setValue(this.ediTradingPartners[0].interchange_id);
        this.f.tmx_interchange_id.setValue(this.ediTradingPartners[0].tmx_interchange_id);

      });
  }

  save(data): void {

    this.interchange_id = data.interchange_id;
    this.tp_name = data.tp_name;
    this.tmx_interchange_id = data.tmx_interchange_id;


    this.ediTradingPartnerService
      .updateEdiTradingPartner(this.tp_name, this.interchange_id, this.tmx_interchange_id)
      .subscribe(() => this.reloadComp());
  }

  reloadComp(): void {

    this.router.navigateByUrl('', {
      skipLocationChange: true
    }).then(() =>
      this.router.navigate(["/ediTradingPartners"]));
  }
}
```

**Service**

```ts
export class EdiTradingPartnerService {

  EdiTradingPartner: EdiTradingPartner;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private h1: Http) {}

  baseUrl: string = 'http://cbintranet3/edireport/editracker-api/index.php/edi_trading_partner';

  // Get all EDI Trading Partners
  getEdiTradingPartners() {
    return this.http.get < EdiTradingPartner[] > (this.baseUrl);
  }

  add(tp_name, interchange_id, tmx_interchange_id) {

    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form=urlencoded');
    console.log(EdiTradingPartner);


    // Add an EDI Trading Partner


    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/add', {
      tp_name: tp_name,
      interchange_id: interchange_id,
      tmx_interchange_id: tmx_interchange_id
    }, {
      responseType: 'text'
    });

  }

  // Delete an EDI Trading Partner
  deleteEdiTradingPartner(edi_trading_partner_id: number) {

    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + '/' + edi_trading_partner_id)
  }

  getEdiTradingPartnerById(id: number) {
    ///
    return this.h1.get(this.baseUrl + '/' + id)
      .map((data: Response) => {
        return data.json();
      })
  }

  updateEdiTradingPartner(interchange_id, tp_name, tmx_interchange_id) {

    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form=urlencoded');
    let EdiTradingPartnerId = localStorage.getItem("EdiTradingPartnerId");

    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + '/update/' + parseInt(EdiTradingPartnerId), {
      interchange_id: interchange_id,
      tp_name: tp_name,
      tmx_interchange_id: interchange_id
    }, {
      responseType: 'text'
    });
  }
}
```

**API**

```php
<?php

  // Call database connection
  require_once('dbconnect.php');

// Display all records
  $app->get('/edi_trading_partner', function($req, $res) {

    $query = "SELECT *
          FROM edi_trading_partner
          order by id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $data[] = $row;
    }

    if(isset($data)) {

      return $res->withJson($data);
      return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
  });
  // Display single row
  $app->get('/edi_trading_partner/select/{id}', function($res) {

    $id = $res->getAttribute('id');


    $query = "SELECT *
          FROM edi_trading_partner
          WHERE id=$id";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

      $data[] = $row;
    }

    if(isset($data)) {

      return json_encode($data);
      return $res->withJson($data);
    } else {

      return json_encode($err_msg);
    }

    mysql_close($conn);

  });

  // Add new trading partner
  $app->post('/edi_trading_partner/add', function() {

    $adddata=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    if(sizeof($adddata)!=0){

      $tp_name=$adddata->tp_name;
      $interchange_id=$adddata->interchange_id;
      $tmx_interchange_id=$adddata->tmx_interchange_id;
      $num = 0;
 $count = "SELECT * FROM edi_user order by id";
     $result1 = mysql_query($count);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
      $num++;
    }
    $num++;

      $query = "INSERT into edi_trading_partner (
            interchange_id,
            tp_name,
            tp_location,
            flag,
            creation_date,
            created_by,
            update_date,
            updated_by,
            tmx_interchange_id)
            values (
            '$interchange_id', 
            '$tp_name', 
            '$tp_location', 
            '$flag',
            '$creation_date',
            '$created_by', 
            '$update_date',
            '$updated_by',
            '$tmx_interchange_id')";

      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(json_encode(array('error' => 'error lang'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

      echo json_encode(array('success' => 'added'));

      if(isset($result)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);
      }

    mysql_close($conn);

    }
  });

  // Delete trading partner
  $app->map(['GET', 'DELETE'],'/edi_trading_partner/delete/{edi_trading_partner_id}', function($req, $res, $args) {

    $edi_trading_partner_id = $req->getAttribute('edi_trading_partner_id');

    $query = "DELETE from edi_trading_partner
          WHERE edi_trading_partner_id='$edi_trading_partner_id'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(!$result) {

      return json_encode(
        array("message" => "Unable to delete this trading partner!")
      );
    } else {

      return json_encode(
        array("message" => "Trading partner successfully deleted!")
      );


    }
  });
  //Update a EDI
  $app->map(['GET', 'PUT'], '/edi_trading_partner/update/{id}', function($req, $res, $args) {

  $updatedata=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  if(sizeof($updatedata)!=0){

   $id = $req->getAttribute('id');
   $tp_name=$updatedata->interchange_id;
   $interchange_id=$updatedata->tp_name; 
   $tmx_interchange_id=$updatedata->tmx_interchange_id;
  $query = "UPDATE edi_trading_partner SET interchange_id = '$interchange_id', tp_name = '$tp_name',, tmx_interchange_id = '$tmx_interchange_id' WHERE id='$id'";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(json_encode(array('error' => 'error lang'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


  if(isset($result)) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);
      }
    mysql_close($conn);
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me with this? I felt so complicated in this code. Kindly check with my code if you are willing to help me. Thank you

Comment: You have to elaborate more on *"I can't update the data"* - do you get some error or what? Is this whole code related to your issue?

Comment: What exactly is not working, in which place exactly is it going wrong? What have you done so far to try and solve this? IMHO you don’t need a “mentor” (or maybe you do, but this is not the right place to look for one), but some basic debugging skills. The most basic steps of debugging should really be dictated by common sense already – _verify_ that variables actual contain what you think they should, _check_ return values of function calls to see if they succeeded or not, etc. So go and make a start on that, and report back with the results.

Comment: Yes that is my whole code but there is no error issues

Comment: The exact not working about this code is I can't update data. Please try to look at my code what do you think is the problem. I don't have any idea about the problem because there is no error